# cannot access elements inside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I cannot get jquery to access elements inside of an event function:

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/w3zv5t0s/2/

On page load, in document.ready you can see the slider go to 10.  However, on a toggle switch, nothing happens, it should go to 1.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   //WORKS HERE
   $(".dimmerSlider").val(10).slider("refresh");

   $('.toggle').on("slidestop", function() {

    //NOT HERE
        $(".dimmerSlider").val(1).slider("refresh");

   });

 });
```

HTML:

```
<select class='toggle' id='3' data-role='slider' data-itemID='3'>
  <option value='ON'>On</option>
  <option value='OFF' selected='selected'>Off</option>
</select>

<input class='dimmerSlider' type='range' id='3' value='15' min='0' max='15' step='1' data-highlight='true' data-itemID='sl3' />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to delegate the `change` event ( instead of `slidestop` ) before you invoke the `slider` function.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.toggle').on("change", function() {
      $(".dimmerSlider").val(1).slider("refresh");    
   });

   $(".dimmerSlider").val(10).slider("refresh");
 });
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/w3zv5t0s/3/

Comment: This does not seem to work with jquery mobile...as soon as I add the jquery mobile file back in it stops working, im using 1.4.5

Comment: the problem looks like its with my code somewhere else, it works in jfiddle.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using a range input with a jQueryUI slider.

If you want to use the slider widget, according to the documentation at http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/, you'd probably use a div and instantiate it with an option setting the value.  You would then use the **slider** calls to make further updates.  Be sure to include the jQuery UI code with your page.

```
<select class='toggle' id='3' data-role='slider' data-itemID='3'>
  <option value='ON'>On</option>
  <option value='OFF' selected='selected'>Off</option>
</select>

<div class='dimmerSliderDiv'></div>

<input class='dimmerSliderInput' type='range' id='3' value='15' min='0' max='15' step='1' data-highlight='true' data-itemID='sl3' />

 $(document).ready(function() {
 $(".dimmerSliderDiv").slider({
   "value": 10
 }); $(".dimmerSliderInput").val(10);
   $('.toggle').on("change", function() {
       $(".dimmerSliderDiv").slider("option", "value", ($(this).val() === "OFF") ? 0 : 15);
       $(".dimmerSliderInput").val(($(this).val() === "OFF") ? 0 : 15);
   });
 });
```

If you are planning to use the range input, you would use the **val** method to set the value.